# How to use conditional elements with pug and not break DRY

Tags: pug

```
if list_type=='unordered'
  ul
    for item in items
      li= item
else 
  ol
    for item in items
      li= item
```

I'd like to not repeat myself by defining the `for` loop twice. How can I do that with Pug?

Comment: Probably the best solution is to create a mixin to not code the the contents twice, but still i have to include it for each case and im wondering if there is another solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most terse way to approach this would be to combine tag interpolation with a ternary conditional. However, this has a negative impact on readability. A less terse [mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) approach may be better for maintainability.

```
#{list_type == 'unordered' ? 'ul' : 'ol'}
  for item in items
    li= item
```

Comment: Interesting, but sadly this functionality is not implemented in pypugjs, damn ;/